# For loops to send info to a constructor in Java

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm trying to use a `for loop` to allow a user to set objects of my class.

To be honest this is a `homework project`, but we haven't gotten to `for loops` yet, I just thought it would be cool to be a little advanced.

But, when I type the part where the input is sent to the method, it says that `non-static` variable cannot be used in `static` context.

Is there a way to do this, or do I have to use 2X's as many variables and lines of code to set up these objects?

Here's the part with the for loops

```
 for (int x=1; x<=2; x++)
   {
    //get input before setting up 2 objects of Employee
    Scanner input = new Scanner ( System.in);
    System.out.print("\nPlease enter the employee's name");
    name = input.nextLine();

    Scanner input1 = new Scanner ( System.in);
    System.out.print("\nPlease enter the employee's department");
    dept = input1.nextLine();

    Scanner input2 = new Scanner ( System.in);
    System.out.print("\nPlease enter the employee's name");
    wage = input2.nextdouble();

    // set Employee objects 
    if (x == 1) {
        Employee_irishRodger employee1 = new Employee_irishRodger(name, dept, wage);
    } else {
        Employee_irishRodger employee2 = new Employee_irishRodger(name, dept, wage);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post that method where you are sending it?? Probably your method is static..

Comment: Why are you opening three scanners for `System.in`? Just use the same one for all the reading.

Comment: You'll need to declare the `Employee_irishRodger` objects outside the loop, otherwise you won't be able to use them after.

Comment: What line gives the error about static context? And can you show the method declaration where this for loop lives?

Comment: Why have you used if else in your code?

Comment: For those people trying to add the `homework` tag: [It's deprecated.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)

Comment: @user1727074.. If you read the compiler error correctly.. It will tell you exactly which non-static variable you are using in static context..

Comment: @vikiiii: they haven't got to for loops yet so probably haven't got to lists/arrays either.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming `name`, `dept` and `wage` are the non-static fields of some class. The reason you are receiving an error is because the method in which you are using the `for`-loop is in fact `static` (not associated with each instance of your class) and hence your non-static fields can not be accessed through it. Try removing the `static` keyword from your method header.

You can read more about the `static` keyword [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

---

On another note, you don't need to create a new `Scanner` each time, you can just keep using `input`. Furthermore, you can instantiate this `Scanner` outside the scope of the `for` loop:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
for (int x = 1 ; x <= 2 ; x++) {
    System.out.print("\nPlease enter the employee's name");
    name = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("\nPlease enter the employee's department");
    dept = input.nextLine();

    System.out.print("\nPlease enter the employee's name");
    wage = input.nextdouble();

    ...
}
input.close();  // don't forget to close the scanner when you're done
```

We've gone from 6 `Scanner` instantiations to 1.

Comment: I was wondering about the Scanner issue, but I haven't seen any examples yet of inputting more than 1 thing at a time before.  Thank you.  Yes, my main is static because that's the only way I've seen it.  What's the input.close() method.  It's looking like I'll leave off the for loop for now because later in the code, I still need a way to refer back to each employee's wage.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I'd do it more like this.  You can have as many employees as you like:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int numEmployees = 5;
List<Employee_irishRodger> employees = new List<Employee_irishRodger>();
for (int i = 0; i < numEmployees; ++i) {
    System.out.print("\nPlease enter the employee's name");
    String name = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("\nPlease enter the employee's department");
    String dept = input.nextLine();
    System.out.print("\nPlease enter the employee's wage");
    String wage = input.nextLine();
    employees.add(new Employee_irishRodger(name, dept, wage));
}
```

I don't know where the class name `Employee_irishRodger` comes from.  Why not just `Employee`?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you're using arrays.  We're definitely not there yet, but it does look like a great solution.  I'm using my name as part of the class because the prof wants it that way.  But thank you

Comment: Not arrays, a List from the Java collections.  You might not be there today, but you should be soon.  I'm leaving my answer as-is because I care less about your question and more about where you'll be later.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Make `name`, `dept` and `wage` local.